# How do you go about proving the existence of a polynomial in an ideal?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

The proof I am looking to prove and understand is as follows:

Consider $P,Q \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and let $I:=<P,Q>$ be the ideal generated by $P$ and $Q$. Prove that there exists a polynomial $G \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $I=<G>$.

How exactly would I begin to prove this, I have only begun studying ideals and polynomial rings for the last three weeks, so really want to understand how to complete the proofs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if $I=<G>=<P,Q>$, then $P$ and $Q$ are multiples of $G$. So $G$ is a common divisor of $P$ and $Q$. Can you see how to continue?

Comment: @Taladris sorry I'm very new to proofs when working with ideals, so I'm not very sure how to carry on.

Comment: Do you know about euclidean division in polynomial rings ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be the greatest common divisor of $P$ and $Q$.

Since $P$ and $Q$ are multiple of $G$, then $P,Q \in <G>$, which implies that $<P,Q>\subset <G>$.

For the other inclusion, Bezout's Theorem says that there exists polynomials $U$ and $V$ such that $G=PU+QV$. Therefore, $G$ is an element of $<P,Q>$, so $<G>\subset<P,Q>$.

As a conclusion, we have $<P,Q>=<G>$.